# SAP Cloud Platform Trial - The HDI container could not be opened

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I'm following the SAP tutorial [Create an application using SAP HANA and the Cloud Application Programming model](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/xsa-e2e-capm-fullstack.html#57ec5db6-bde3-4668-ae7b-61f904f61828). Steps 1-4 have been successfully completed - I even get the output "1:44:30 PM (HDB) Build of /APP/db completed successfully." at the end of step 4.

When I right click on the db folder and chose Open HDI Container the below error occurs.

[image]

The applications running in my space I are below.

[image]

Info about my space.

[image]

Below are the service instances in my dev space.

[image]

Am I:

1. Doing something wrong,
2. Missing some prerequisite, or
3. Does this not work in the trial account?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hdi container is indeed there (go into service instances, not applications), it may be because of the region. Change the region of your trial to Europe Frankfurt: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/16/how-to-change-the-region-in-your-cloud-foundry-trial/

Cheers,

Lucia.

Comment: I added some additional details. My space is currently in region US East (VA). Does this mean I need to create a new space in Frankfurt?

Comment: Looks like neither of the Europe Cloud Foundry regions (Frankfurt & Netherlands) has HDI container available in the service marketplace. Are you referring to a Neo region?